# making a linegraph that shows population decay with dc.js and crossfilter

Tags: data-visualization, dc.js, crossfilter

I am creating a dashboard in DC.js. One of the visualizations is a survival curve showing the percentage of survival on the y-axis and the time in weeks on the x-axis

Each record in the dataset contains a deathAfter column called `recidiefNa`. This shows the number of weeks after death occurred, and shows -99 for survival.

See sketches for example dataset and desired chart form:
[image: sketch of desired outcome]

I created this code to create the dimensions and groups and draw the desired chart.

```
var recDim = cf1.dimension(dc.pluck('recidiefNa'));//sets dimension
            var recGroup = recDim.group().reduceCount();

            var resDim = cf1.dimension(dc.pluck('residuNa'));
            var resGroup = resDim.group().reduceCount();



            var scChart = dc.compositeChart("#scStepChart");
            scChart
            .width(600)
            .height(400)
            .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,52]))
            .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,100]))
            .clipPadding(10)
            .brushOn(false)
            .xAxisLabel("tijd in weken")
            .yAxisLabel("percentage vrij van residu/recidief")
            .compose([
                dc.lineChart(scChart)
                    .dimension(recDim)
                    .group(recGroup)
                    .interpolate("step-after")
                    .renderDataPoints(true)
                    .renderTitle(true)
                    .keyAccessor(function(d){return d.key;})
                    .valueAccessor(function(d){return (d.value/cf1.groupAll().reduceCount().value()*100);}),
                dc.lineChart(scChart)
                    .dimension(resDim)
                    .group(resGroup)
                    .interpolate("step-after")
                    .renderDataPoints(true)
                    .colors(['orange'])
                    .renderTitle(true)
                    .keyAccessor(function(d){return d.key;})
                    .valueAccessor(function(d){return (d.value/cf1.groupAll().reduceCount().value()*100 );})
            ])                    
            .xAxis().ticks(4);
            scChart.render();
```

This gives the following result:

[image: first attempt]

As you can see my first problem is that I need the line to extend until the y-axis showing x=0weeks and y=100% as the first datapoint.

So that's question number one: is there a way to get that line to look more like my sketch(starting on the y-axis at 100%?

My second and **bigger problem** is that it is showing the inverse of the percentage I need (eg. 38 instead of 62). This is because of the way the data is structured (which is somehting i rather not change)

First I tried changing the valueaccessor to 100-*calculated number. Which is obviously the normal way to solve this issue. However my result was this:

[image: with value accessor]

As you can see now the survival curve is a positive incline which is never possible in a survival curve. This is my second question. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: http://s9.postimg.org/thez0lrgv/db2.png

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is a restatement of [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631806/making-a-survival-curve-chart-in-dc-js). If so, you should close that one since this is better stated.

Comment: I don't really understand how the values could be inverted and stay decreasing. If x1 > x2 then 100-x1 < 100-x2. Perhaps if you show how they are calculated? As for your first question, if you just add a data point for x=0, y=100, that should do it. You can do this dynamically by using a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups).

Comment: Hi there, the numbers are inverted correctly because x1 isn't always bigger than x2. what is recorded in the dataset are the number of people that do have decay. So to get the numbers i would need to have x0=100, x1=100-x1, x2=100-x1-x1 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it wasn't clear from the particular example that each data point should be based on the last, but your comment makes that clear. It sounds like what you are looking for is a kind of cumulative sum - in your case, a cumulative subtraction.

[There is an entry in the FAQ for this.](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#accumulate-values)

Adapting that code to your use case:

```
function accumulate_subtract_from_100_group(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            var cumulate = 100;
            return source_group.all().map(function(d) {
                cumulate -= d.value;
                return {key:d.key, value:cumulate};
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var decayRecGroup = accumulate_subtract_from_100_group(recGroup)
   // ...
      dc.lineChart(scChart)
         // ...
            .group(decayRecGroup)
```

and similarly for the `resGroup`

While we're at it, we can concatenate the data to the initial point, to answer your first question:

```
function accumulate_subtract_from_100_and_prepend_start_point_group(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            var cumulate = 100;
            return [{key: 0, value: cumulate}]
               .concat(source_group.all().map(function(d) {
                  cumulate -= d.value;
                  return {key:d.key, value:cumulate};
               }));
        }
    };
}
```

(ridiculous function name for exposition only!)

EDIT: here is @Erik's final adapted answer with the percentage conversion built in, and a couple of performance improvements:

```
function fakeGrouper(source_group) {
    var groupAll = cf1.groupAll().reduceCount();
    return {
        all:function () {
            var cumulate = 100;
            var total = groupAll.value();
            return [{key: 0, value: cumulate}]
                .concat(source_group.all().map(function(d) {
                    if(d.key > 0) {             
                        cumulate -= (d.value/total*100).toFixed(0);
                    }
                    return {key:d.key, value:cumulate};
                }));
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: OW and sorry one more thing, atm i am using -99 in my dataset for no decay. Will this still work for that or should i use something else for that

Comment: It is not completely working yet, i added an extra 150 rows to the dataset and now the chart isn't rendering correectly. I think this is because the value in the data is not the percentage but just the number. The percentage still needs to be calculated, Where do i add this calculation. Is it in the fake group

Comment: Hi @ErikWestra, I don't see an update - did this end up working for you?

Comment: I edited some code in the answer, think it needsto be reviewed first

Comment: Ah right I forgot about the review queue. Glad this mostly worked and eager to see what you finally came up with!

Comment: I thought i would show you the code i ended up while we're waiting for review its added in the question

Comment: Not sure what happened to your edit; I moved your adapted answer from the question to the answer and improved it a little (calling `groupAll()` within the loop is potentially very slow).

Comment: Specifically, you shouldn't call `groupAll()` within a loop since it is creating permanent objects which will slow down crossfilter as a whole.